# Have anyone implemented NEDNSProxyManager before?

Tags: ios, networkextension

I tried to use the NEDNSProxyManager to redirect the dns to my own server but failed to do that.
It should be able to do that as based on Apple Documentation

A DNS proxy allows your app to intercept all DNS traffic generated on a device. You can use this capability to provide services like DNS traffic encryption, typically by redirecting DNS traffic to your own server. You usually do this in the context of managed devices, such as those owned by a school or an enterprise.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you describe your problem more clearly?  What did you try? What happened?

Comment: i followed the answer over here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508605/how-to-use-nednsproxyprovider-in-ios-11?answertab=votes#tab-top .              
I searched for the Apple official documentation, nothing much guidance on how to redirect the DNS or filter them.

Comment: Ok, but what problems are you having? What happens? What debugging have you tried? Do you see any errors or other messages in the device console?

Comment: The integration was fine just that I don’t know how to redirect the DNS.
This is from the Device Console when I use Safari:
default 11:58:55.548300 +0800 DNSProxy flow_director_handle_connect:2657 (0): Flow 4073160882 is connecting
default 11:58:55.548376 +0800 DNSProxy flow_director_handle_connect:2770 (4073160882): New flow: NEFlow type = datagram, app = com.apple.mobilesafari, name = , address = 1.1.1.1, port = 53)

1.1.1.1  is the DNS I set through the Device Wifi Settings.