# Starter code to monitor DHCP, m-DNS,DNS traffic in iOS

Tags: ios, dns, dhcp, mdns, networkextension

We are new to iOS apple development and iOS network extension but we do have general application development experience. We are wondering if there is a starter code available which we could utilize for our project.
We are looking for a virtual network interface in iOS so could monitor network traffic. Our goal is to monitor DHCP broadcast,m-DNS, DNS traffic.

If there are other methods, we would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can intercept DNS traffic in NE. However, if you are only interested in capturing DNS traffic, [DNS Proxy Provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/dns_proxy_provider) would your best option. Although, DNS Proxy Provider has limitation that it is only supported on managed devices.

Few discussions that would help:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81103?answerId=246229022
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665480
[How to use NEDNSProxyProvider in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508605/how-to-use-nednsproxyprovider-in-ios-11)

Few samples on GitHub:
https://github.com/pusateri/DNS-TLS
https://github.com/GroupeMINASTE/FMobile-iOS

You can search for `NEDNSProxyProvider` in developer forums to find quite a few discussions about it. This discussion also provides some good details. Also, this one.

You may also use [Packet Tunnel Provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/packet_tunnel_provider) with match domains or empty match domains and full tunnel. This will allow you to support NE without MDM.

Few examples of Packet Tunnel Providers:
https://github.com/douxinchun/RabbitVpnDemo
https://github.com/OperatorFoundation/PacketTunnelExample
https://github.com/davlxd/NEPacketTunnelVPNDemo